# Jquery button .hover not registering

Tags: jquery, html

I am a bit stumped as to what my problem is, and it probably has a simple solution but I can't seem to get it to work.

I just want to have a button fade in and out when you hover over it.

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".client-login").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(150,0.7);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    }
);
</script>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header id="main-header">
    <div id="top-menu">
        <div id="login-buttons">
            <div class="client-login">Client Login</div>
        </div>
...
```

Comment: wrap it in document ready, a tiny bit of googling would of solved this

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your jquery document.ready

//shorthand of document.ready is $(function(){});

```
 $(function () {
    $(".client-login").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(150,0.7);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks man,  I knew it would end up being something simple.  It's been a long day.

Comment: @PStokes Please remember to select a correct answer, and to upvote any answers that are helpful to you. If desired, you can both upvote an answer and select the same answer as the correct answer.

Comment: No worries, we all have em. Just things you gotta get used to and drill into habit. You mind marking my answer as correct then, I like the points! lol